# RESful ASP.NET WEB API paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a simple ASP.NET WEB API (MVC 4). But I don't know how to do size and paging. My query below returned 1000 records which it takes time to load one time.

For my controller here's the source code:

```
public GRPORequestData[] getAllGRPO()
    {
        List<GRPORequestData> list = new List<GRPORequestData>();

        try
        {
            string sqlSelect = "SELECT DocEntry, CardCode, Comments, DocDate, DocDueDate FROM OINV WHERE DataSource = 'O' ";
            APPTech.strCommand = sqlSelect;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt = APPTech.Ds.Tables[0];

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                // Person target = Activator.CreateInstance();
                GRPORequestData target = new GRPORequestData();
                target.docEntry = row["DocEntry"].ToString();
                target.supplier = row["CardCode"].ToString();
                target.docdate = row["DocDate"].ToString();
                target.duedate = row["DocDueDate"].ToString();
                target.remarks = row["Comments"].ToString();
                // DataColumnAttribute.Bind(row,target);

                sqlSelect = "SELECT ItemCode, Quantity, Price, WhsCode, TaxCode FROM INV1 WHERE DocEntry = '" + row["DocEntry"].ToString() + "' ";
                APPTech.strCommand = sqlSelect;

                List<RequestDataDetails> requestDetails = new List<RequestDataDetails>();

                for (var i = 0; i < APPTech.Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    requestDetails.Add(new RequestDataDetails
                    {
                        itemCode = APPTech.GetDs(0, i).ToString(),
                        quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(APPTech.GetDs(1, i)),
                        price = Convert.ToDecimal(APPTech.GetDs(2, i)),
                        whscode = APPTech.GetDs(3, i).ToString(),
                        taxcode = APPTech.GetDs(4, i).ToString()
                    });
                }
                target.DocumentLines = requestDetails.ToArray();

                list.Add(target);
            }

            return list.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.ToString();
        }

        return list.ToArray();

    }
```

And for my Model:

```
    public class GRPORequestData
{ 
    public string docEntry { get; set; }

    public string supplier { get; set; }

    public string docdate { get; set; }

    public string duedate { get; set; }

    public string remarks { get; set; }

    //[DataMember]
    //public int rowcount { get; set; }

    public RequestDataDetails[] DocumentLines;
}

public class RequestDataDetails
{ 
    public string itemCode { get; set; }

    public decimal quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal price { get; set; }

    public string whscode { get; set; }

    public string taxcode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do a `JOIN` and only use one select statement, instead of additional n queries per row returned?

Comment: so your question is how to do sizing and paging on your aspx page?

Comment: What is `APPTech`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how many records are displayed per page and on which page you are.

Then you need to change the signature of your method:

```
public GRPORequestData[] getAllGRPO(int pageSize, int pageNr) { ... }
```

As a last step you need to built this into your select statement, to get only those values, which fit to your page number.

If you have 10 records per page and are on page 5, that means you will have to skip the records 1 - 40 and display 41-50.

```
WITH RowNumberResults AS
(
    //Assuming DocEntry is your primary key / identity column
    SELECT DocEntry, CardCode, Comments, DocDate, DocDueDate, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DocEntry) AS rn
    FROM OINV WHERE     DataSource = 'O' 
)
SELECT *
FROM RowNumberResults
WHERE rn BETWEEN @Skip AND @rest
```

Now you need to specify `@Skip` and `@Rest` as SqlParameters and add the values in.
Based on my example above that would be for Skip: `pageSize * (page -1)` and for Rest: `(pageSize * 5) + 1`

Assuming your object APPTech is able to add SqlParameters to your command:

```
APPTech.strCommand.Parameters.Add("@Skip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pageSize * (page -1); 
APPTech.strCommand.Parameters.Add("@Rest", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (pageSize * 5) + 1;
```